# Problem With nginx and wordpress subfolder install -- permalinks not working

Tags: wordpress, nginx, permalinks, subdirectory

Wordpress index page (default post url) working but posts are not once I switch to custom permalink

wordpress 5.0.3
nginx 1.14.0

my nginx file

```
server {

listen 80:
listen [::]:80;

server_name www.example.com;

root /var/www/html;
index index.html;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /blog {
    alias /var/www/wp;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /test {
    alias /var/www/test;
    try_file $uri $uri/ =404;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}
}
```

**my folder structure:**

/var/www/html -> http://www.example.com/

/var/www/wp -> http://www.example.com/blog

**Working:**

http://www.example.com

http://www.example.com/test

http://www.example.com/blog/?p=123

**Not working:**

http://www.example.com/blog/archives/123

http://www.example.com/blog/sample-post/

Comment: Let me know if you need other details - started with the basics

Comment: I do not understand how the URI `/index.php` finds the file `/var/www/wp/index.php`.

Comment: @RichardSmith sorry i'm not sure i understand. here's what i did to test: created folder /var/www/test and placed a simple index.html file and **nginx alias** (see alias above) to /test - it works but wordpress still broken